# How to get environment from a subprocess?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, environment-variables, popen

I want to call a process via a python program, however, this process need some specific environment variables that are set by another process. How can I get the first process environment variables to pass them to the second?

This is what the program look like:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['proc1']) # this set env. variables for proc2
subprocess.call(['proc2']) # this must have env. variables set by proc1 to work
```

but the to process don't share the same environment. Note that these programs aren't mine (the first is big and ugly .bat file and the second a proprietary soft) so I can't modify them (ok, I can extract all that I need from the .bat but it's very combersome).

N.B.: I am using Windows, but I prefer a cross-platform solution (but my problem wouldn't happen on a Unix-like ...)

Comment: A .bat file?  If you're running in Windows, you should really say so clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're apparently in Windows, you need a Windows answer.

Create a wrapper batch file, eg. "run_program.bat", and run both programs:

```
@echo off
call proc1.bat
proc2
```

The script will run and set its environment variables.  Both scripts run in the same interpreter (cmd.exe instance), so the variables prog1.bat sets *will* be set when prog2 is executed.

Not terribly pretty, but it'll work.

(Unix people, you can do the same thing in a bash script: "source file.sh".)

Comment: I am specifically trying to work around using `sourch blah; now_do_second_thing`

Answer (score 31):

Here's an example of how you can extract environment variables from a batch or cmd file without creating a wrapper script. Enjoy.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import subprocess
import itertools

def validate_pair(ob):
    try:
        if not (len(ob) == 2):
            print("Unexpected result:", ob, file=sys.stderr)
            raise ValueError
    except:
        return False
    return True

def consume(iter):
    try:
        while True: next(iter)
    except StopIteration:
        pass

def get_environment_from_batch_command(env_cmd, initial=None):
    """
    Take a command (either a single command or list of arguments)
    and return the environment created after running that command.
    Note that if the command must be a batch file or .cmd file, or the
    changes to the environment will not be captured.

    If initial is supplied, it is used as the initial environment passed
    to the child process.
    """
    if not isinstance(env_cmd, (list, tuple)):
        env_cmd = [env_cmd]
    # construct the command that will alter the environment
    env_cmd = subprocess.list2cmdline(env_cmd)
    # create a tag so we can tell in the output when the proc is done
    tag = 'Done running command'
    # construct a cmd.exe command to do accomplish this
    cmd = 'cmd.exe /s /c "{env_cmd} && echo "{tag}" && set"'.format(**vars())
    # launch the process
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env=initial)
    # parse the output sent to stdout
    lines = proc.stdout
    # consume whatever output occurs until the tag is reached
    consume(itertools.takewhile(lambda l: tag not in l, lines))
    # define a way to handle each KEY=VALUE line
    handle_line = lambda l: l.rstrip().split('=',1)
    # parse key/values into pairs
    pairs = map(handle_line, lines)
    # make sure the pairs are valid
    valid_pairs = filter(validate_pair, pairs)
    # construct a dictionary of the pairs
    result = dict(valid_pairs)
    # let the process finish
    proc.communicate()
    return result
```

So to answer your question, you would create a .py file that does the following:

```
env = get_environment_from_batch_command('proc1')
subprocess.Popen('proc2', env=env)
```

Comment: An edit suggested that the implementation as written doesn't support non-ASCII code pages. In that case, the recommended fix was to place `chcp 65001 > NULL && ` before `{env_cmd}` in the cmd construction.

Comment: Here is more updated version of this function https://github.com/PySide/pyside2-setup/blob/master/utils.py#L379

Comment: This is not cross-platform, as OP requested.

Comment: That's right, it's not generally possible to extract the environment from a running process, as seen in Martin v. Löwis' answer. This answer focuses on the OP's problem at hand. Presumably, this would work cross platform if you had `cmd.exe` on that platform, which you would if you're working with a batch file for proc1.

Answer (score 5):

As you say, processes don't share the environment - so what you literally ask is not possible, not only in Python, but with any programming language.

What you *can* do is to put the environment variables in a file, or in a pipe, and either

- have the parent process read them, and pass them to proc2 before proc2 is created, or
- have proc2 read them, and set them locally

The latter would require cooperation from proc2; the former requires that the variables become known before proc2 is started.

Comment: Under Linux, if you are root, you can check /proc/<pid>/environ and parse it... not "impossible".

Comment: @0x6abd015: however, this is not what the OP asks: he doesn't want proc2 find out what proc1's environment is (what you can do with the proc file system), but he wants proc1 to *set* environment for proc2 - I still claim that this impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Process` in [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) to get the environment variables for that Process.

If you want to implement it yourself, you can refer to the internal implementation of [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#). It adapts to some operating system.

Currently supported operating systems are:

- AIX
- FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD
- Linux
- macOS
- Sun Solaris
- Windows

Eg: In Linux platform, you can find one pid 7877 environment variables in file `/proc/7877/environ`, just open with `rt` mode to read it.

Of course the best way to do this is to:

```
import os
from typing import Dict
from psutil import Process

process = Process(pid=os.getpid())
process_env: Dict = process.environ()

print(process_env)
```

You can find other platform implementation in [source code](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/tree/master/psutil)

Hope I can help you.

Comment: Accordingly to https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#processes, the ``environ()`` method might not contain the changes of the environment after it started, so this would render this approach invalid

Comment: @drodri I just [tested it](https://superuser.com/a/1756388/282374) on Windows 10, and it *does* contain the changes. I think that warning is about other operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

[The Python standard module multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) have a Queues system that allow you to pass pickle-able object to be passed through processes. Also processes can exchange messages (a pickled object) using os.pipe. Remember that resources (e.g : database connection) and handle (e.g : file handles) can't be pickled.

You may find this link interesting :
[Communication between processes with multiprocessing](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/communication.html)

Also the PyMOTw about multiprocessing worth mentioning :
[multiprocessing Basics](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/basics.html)

sorry for my spelling

Answer (score 0):

Two things spring to mind: (1) make the processes share the same environment, by combining them somehow into the same process, or (2) have the first process produce output that contains the relevant environment variables, that way Python can read it and construct the environment for the second process. I think (though I'm not 100% sure) that there isn't any way to get the environment from a subprocess as you're hoping to do.

Answer (score 0):

elaborating on Jason R. Coombs answers, I needed something that would work on unix system, and I made it working also for Windows, so it's portable (tested on Windows 10 and AIX7.2):

```py
import subprocess
import os

def get_environment_from_batch_command(script):
    def validate_pair(ob):
        if not (len(ob) == 2):
            return False
        return True

    handle_line = lambda l: l.rstrip().split("=", 1)

    if os.name == "nt":
        command = f'cmd.exe /E:ON /V:ON /s /c "{script} > NUL && set"'
    else:
        command = f". {script} > /dev/null 2>&1; printenv"

    print(command)
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        shell=True,
    )
    stdout = p.communicate()[0]
    stdout_lines = stdout.decode("utf-8").split("\n")
    pairs = map(handle_line, stdout_lines)
    valid_pairs = filter(validate_pair, pairs)
    result = dict(valid_pairs)
    return result
```

Examples to use it:

```py
    environment = get_environment_from_batch_command(script)
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        commands,
        env=environment,
    )
    cp = subprocess.run(
        commands,
        env=environment,
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Environment is inherited from the parent process.  Set the environment you need in the main script, not a subprocess (child).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. There are good reasons against doing this too, if you have programs that need conflicting ENV vars set, for example.

Comment: Standard environment variables will be the same in the new shell/interpreter instance, but temporary environment variables, creates with 'export' in the bash shell or 'os.environ' in the python shell/script are not inherited by default. There is an optional argument 'env' thought, that enables such inheritance

Comment: @TheDronist A shell variable that is exported by bash is in the environment of the child.  Indeed, that is the entire point of 'export'.  All values in 'os.environ' are also inherited into the environment of the child.   The `env` optional argument to Popen allows you to specify additional values that will also be in the environment.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It helped me get a clearer understanding. I changed two things in one step  recently and missed how the inheritance works.