# Python subprocess.Popen and retaining environment

Tags: python, popen, environment

### The problem

I call some program via `subprocess.Popen` and the program calls an external password utility, which uses gpg-agent to "unlock the keyring". Hence, almost everytime I run it, I have to unlock the gpg-agent, which is inconvenient to say the least.

I also noticed that if I unlock it for a particular shell session (in the terminal), I do not need to unlock the agent that often.

### The question(s)

How can I retain the environment after I unlock the gpg-agent once via `Popen` and then pass the environment to the subsequent `Popen`s?

Can anybody think of some other way to do this, so that `Popen` calls inherit some specific environment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get environment from a subprocess in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214496/how-to-get-environment-from-a-subprocess-in-python) That one is a Windows version; there is a UNIX variant too which I'll try to find for you as well.

Comment: Basically you have to communicate the env vars with the parent process by adding to the command run.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Currently it works as expected and time (or a reboot) will tell if it really works in this case.