# msbuild, vcvars32 and python

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, subprocess

I'm using VS2012 and are trying to setup an automatic build using python.
I am trying something like this

```
cmd =  'msbuild /p:Configuration=Release INSTALL.vcxproj'
print cmd
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

But it fails becuase the subprocess don't have proper environment variables.

How do I create a process with the environment variables set in vcvars32.bat ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get environment from a subprocess in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214496/how-to-get-environment-from-a-subprocess-in-python)

Comment: The accepted answer at that question is not much use IMHO. However, the highest voted answer is good. I use that exact code to do precisely what you are trying to do here. On the other handle, you can perfectly well do this: `cmd /c call vcvars32.bat && msbuild ...` (you need to fill in the details) and that works fine too.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'll check those out.