# How to detect if a Serverless Framework function is running offline with serverless-offline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am using python, and want to configure the database connection based on whether the function is running offline or deployed to AWS.

Some examples use the environment variable 'IS_OFFLINE', but it doesn't seem to be set.

Was that feature replaced with something else, or only available in the js runtime? What's the right way to detect whether a function is being run offline?

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
console.log(process.env.IS_OFFLINE)
```

https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline#the-processenvis_offline-variable

For Python:

[How to get environment from a subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214496/how-to-get-environment-from-a-subprocess)

Comment: Perfect, thank you, just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, you can access the IS_OFFLINE flag by using this: `os.environ['IS_OFFLINE']`